# copy file from local share to Shared one drive folder

Tags: onedrive, power-automate

I need to copy a file from local file share to Another users one drive folder. The one drive owner has given access to me, and I can manually upload the file through browser.

Need to automate the copy of the file to be run every night.
I tried power-automate flow, but was able to copy into my one drive.

Looking for suggestions/solutions.